# EventHandler is always null?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, uap

I want to create a event and subscribe is on another ViewModel. The event handler is always getting null on the first ViewModel.
In the first Viewmodel I declared Event and raised as follows

```
  public event EventHandler EditSearchChanged;
```

and raised as

```
     if (EditSearchChanged != null)
        {
            EditSearchChanged(this, null);
        }
```

In the second Viewmodel,I have declared a property of first Viewmodel.

```
   private EditTileViewModel editTileVM;

    public EditTileViewModel EditTileVM
    {
        get
        {
            return editTileVM ?? (editTileVM = new EditTileViewModel());
        }
        set
        {
            editTileVM = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

and subscribe the event as follows

```
EditTileVM.EditSearchChanged += EditTileVM_EditSearchChanged;

  private void EditTileVM_EditSearchChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.EditTileVM = (sender as EditTileViewModel);
    }
```

Debugger Result
[image]

Comment: Here EditSearchChanged is null

Comment: Is it possible that the line 'EditTileVM.EditSearchChanged += EditTileVM_EditSearchChanged;' is never executed, and therefore never set? Maybe supply some more code?

Comment: can you place a debugger at `EditTileVM.EditSearchChanged += EditTileVM_EditSearchChanged` and check if it is fired ?

Comment: Added PIC for debugger

Answer (score 0):

It happens as you create another new instance of `ViewModel` in the following property:

```
private EditTileViewModel editTileVM;
public EditTileViewModel EditTileVM
{
    get
    {
        return editTileVM ?? (editTileVM = new EditTileViewModel());
    }
    set
    {
        editTileVM = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

So there are two instances of `EditViewModel`.

I suggest you to use [`EventAggregator` pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.20).aspx?tduid=(f126a1907a9534417700bb4fe65b5b81)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-DRKGJFInbcmWDJ9VqKRuiA)()) between two `viewModels` from Prism framework:

```
// Subscribe
eventAggregator.GetEvent<CloseAppliactionMessage>().Subscribe(ExitMethod);

// Broadcast
eventAggregator.GetEvent<CloseAppliactionMessage>().Publish();
```

Please, see a very good tutorial of Rachel Lim about [simplified Event Aggregator pattern](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/).

Or use [MVVM Light messenger](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/):

```
//Subscribe
Messenger.Default.Register<CloseAppliactionMessage>(ExitMethod);

// Broadcast
Messenger.Default.Send<CloseAppliactionMessage
```